# How to Return a first charc from my column in sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

How to return a first charc from my database column ?

**Explaination :** My problem in detail is, I have set of records like

- Apple

  Alice

  Bat

  Bath

  Cat

and it will keep on going how to return a first charc from that column.  I have tried distinct query with substring but it throws Couldn't read a row how to sort out this issue need to get first charc like **a,b,c..**
Let me post what i have tried so far:

```
 public List<AccountModel> Header(){
    String countQuery ="select DISTINCT lower(substr("+AccountModel.acc_companyname+",1,1)) as char from "+AccountModel.acc_table  +" ";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    List<AccountModel>list=new ArrayList<>();
    if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0){
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                AccountModel accountModel=new AccountModel();
                accountModel.setCompanyName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AccountModel.acc_companyname)));
                 list.add(accountModel);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    if(cursor!=null){
        cursor.setNotificationUri(mcontext.getContentResolver(), DB_Account);
    }
    return list;
}
```

how to get the first charc from my records using distinct and substring and need to set that in list Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your Header method like this:

```
 public Cursor Header(){
        String countQuery = "select DISTINCT lower(substr("+AccountModel.acc_companyname+",1,1)) as inital_char from "+AccountModel.acc_table  +" ";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

Issue was in your substr method.

Original query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(name, 1, 1)) AS indexChar
FROM myTable
ORDER BY indexChar
```

Happy coding!!!!

Comment: still facing the same problem

Comment: try it now replaced char with some thing else as char is one of the data type in sql

Comment: what does initial char

Comment: its is  Alias of your main column

Comment: please check my updated code am getting  couldn't read row 0 make sure cursor is initialized correctly before accessing

Comment: couldn't read row in Accountmodel acc=new AccountModel();acc.setCompanyname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnindex(AccountModel.acc_companyname));

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran : Change _`accountModel.setCompanyName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AccountModel.acc_companyname)));`_ to `accountModel.setCompanyName(cursor.getString(0));`

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran : `cursor.getString()` takes column index as parameter. In your case the query returns only one column i.e.,  is **char**(as defined in the query) which has an index of 0. Whereas you are passing an index of _acc_companyname_ column which has some different index. [cursor.getString() docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString(int))